# Browsers not compatible, Parent Div's height is manipulated by Child Div's and the footer is pushed to the bottom. Pure CSS requested

Tags: html, css, parent-child, sticky-footer

What I am looking to achieve is all the three below

1. pushing the footer to the bottom of the page
2. also making the main div stay full sized all the time with the child divs
3. all the child div's remain same height

I tried so many ways to do it and I found a way. But what ever I have done is not compatible with Firefox, Safari and IE7 and below, Please help me, I am looking for something that works on all browsers and Pure CSS.

Thanks a lot friends.

html:

```
<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="row">
        <div id="childRight">content</div>
        <div id="childLeft"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">footer content</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
            #parent{
                height: auto !important;
                min-height: 100%;
                width: 400px;
                background: grey;
                overflow: auto;
                display: table;
            }
            #footer{
                height: 60px;
                width: 400px;
                background: yellow;
                margin-top: -60px;
            }
            html, body{
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }
            #childRight, #childLeft{
                display: table-cell;
                width: 100px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                min-height: 100%;
            }
            #childRight{
                background: green;
                height: 100px;
            }
            #childLeft{
                background: red;
                height: 200px;
            }
            #row{
                display: table-row;
                background: blue;
            }
</style>
```

JSfiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/yellowandred/UBUNJ/2/

I appreciate your help and suggestions friends. thanks in advance..

[image: Screenshot when used on FF]

Comment: *Its not about pushing the footer to the bottom of the page using CSS* **What I am looking for is to achieve 1. pushing the footer to the bottom of the page**

Comment: sorry, I meant, I am not trying to achieve only one at a time. I want all the tree should go together.. thanks Mr A..

Comment: What's wrong with your fiddle?

Comment: that works fine on google chrome, opera and IE8 and above, but the footer is not pushed down in IE7 and below, firefox and safari..

Comment: I'm using FF and it's in the bottom... Looks exactly like in Chrome. Also, if I may ask, why are you still specifically supporting IE 7?

Comment: I am building a web app for rural indian govt office where they only use IE above 7, that comes with Windows XP..

Comment: also I dont know why my FF is not pushing it down mine is 23.0.1 does that matter..??

Comment: i think it will help http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

Answer (score 0):

Change height of the left and right side div should be same...ex:200px.
and use fixed bottom property for footer.